# Infinity Loop Slider Concepts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder what are the best(good readable code, pest practice code,reusability) concepts to build a Infinity-Image-Loop-Slider for a Website using JavaScript/jQuery? I dont what to know how to code the Slide show but what blueprint matches the requirements mention above.
 The main focus of my question is how to arrange the pictures to get the impression of a infinity loop Slider.

By look at Code from different Sliders I came across two solutions:

-change the z-Index of all Images each time the next/previous image is displayed.

-change the Position of the Image in the DOM.

But examine and understanding the code of   others is very time-consuming - that's why I ask this question :-)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**tl;dr** - JSBin Example: http://jsbin.com/ufoceq/8/

---

A simple approach to create an infinite image slider without too much effort is as follows: let say for the sake of simplicity that you have `<n>` images to slide in a loop, so that after the `n`<sup>th</sup> image the next one to visualize is the `1`<sup>st</sup> (and vice-versa).

The idea is to create a clone of first and last image so that

- the clone of the last image is prepended before the first one;
- the clone of the first image is appended after the last one.

Whatever is the amount of your images, you will need to append at most only 2 cloned elements.

Again for the simplicity, let say that all images are `100px` wide and they're wrapped in a container that you move left/right into a clipped mask with `overflow: hidden`. Then, all images can be easily aligned in a row with `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` set on the container (with `flexbox` now it is even easier).

For `n = 4` The DOM structure would be something like this:

```
offset(px)     0       100     200     300     400     500
images         |   4c   |   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   1c
                                                   
/*                 ^^                                       ^^
       [ Clone of the last image ]              [ Clone of the 1st image ]
*/
```

At the beginning, your container will be positioned with `left: -100px` (or also `margin-left: -100px` [or even better (for a matter of performance)](http://paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) `transform: translateX(-100px)` ), so the slider can show the first image. To switch from an image to another you will need to apply a javascript animation over the same property you've previously chosen.

When your slider is currently at the 4<sup>th</sup> image, you have to switch from image `4` to `1c`, so the idea is to execute a callback at the end of the animation that soon reposition your slider wrapper at the real 1<sup>st</sup> image offset (e.g. you set `left: -100px` to the container)

This is analogous when your slider is currently positioned on the 1<sup>st</sup> element: to show the previous image you just need to perform an animation from image `1` to `4c` and when animation has been completed you just move the container so the slider is istantly positioned at the 4<sup>th</sup> image offset (e.g. you set `left: -400px` to the container).

---

You can see the effect on the above fiddle: this is the minimal `js/jquery` code I used (of course the code can be even optimized so the width of the items is not hardcoded into the script)

```
$(function() {
 
  var gallery = $('#gallery ul'),
      items   = gallery.find('li'),
      len     = items.length,
      current = 1,  /* the item we're currently looking */
      
      first   = items.filter(':first'),
      last    = items.filter(':last'),
      
      triggers = $('button');
  
  /* 1. Cloning first and last item */
  first.before(last.clone(true)); 
  last.after(first.clone(true)); 
  
  /* 2. Set button handlers */
  triggers.on('click', function() {

    var cycle, delta;
    
    if (gallery.is(':not(:animated)')) {
     
        cycle = false;
        delta = (this.id === "prev")? -1 : 1;
        /* in the example buttons have id "prev" or "next" */  
    
        gallery.animate({ left: "+=" + (-100 * delta) }, function() {
      
            current += delta;
       
            /** 
             * we're cycling the slider when the the value of "current" 
             * variable (after increment/decrement) is 0 or when it exceeds
             * the initial gallery length
             */          
            cycle = (current === 0 || current > len);
       
            if (cycle) {
                /* we switched from image 1 to 4-cloned or 
                   from image 4 to 1-cloned */
                current = (current === 0)? len : 1; 
                gallery.css({left:  -100 * current });
            }
        });   
     }
    
  });
});
```

---

As mentioned before, this solution doesn't require really much effort and talking about performance, comparing this approach to a normal slider without looping, it only requires to make two additional DOM insertion when the slider is initialized and some (quite trivial) extra logic to manage a backward/forward loop.

Here is another example when you see two elements at once: in that case you need to clone more elements and make some simple changes to the logic

https://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/bGbjZdz

I don't know if a simpler or better approach exists, but hope this helps anyway.

**Note**: if you need to also have a responsive gallery, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15920259/1098851) may help too

Comment: @user1828928 if you're interested in a live example I created a short fiddle

Comment: Sorry about the first flag. I think wires got crossed there, because you're right about the wiki status here.

Comment: Can do with either 1c OR 4c both not needed.

Comment: awesome, so you should write a fiddle and answer to this question @JithinJose

Comment: Don't understand the point. You're still using two cloned elements

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan , the bin i have created might have expired, http://jsbin.com/tutupelisesu/2. here we are not using 4c

Comment: I think it's better for the whole community if you insert a new answer with a full explanation of your code.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan , it is a small modification of your code, only worth for a comment :)

Comment: How can we make it continuous and pause on hover? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much @fcalderan I was trying for 4 slides. Actually I am trying to create one which is flexible based on numberOfSlides values in my code using vanilla js. It can be 1,2,3,4. I tried:- https://codepen.io/yogeshbv09/pen/JjPaZXQ but its not working as expected. Can you please help me with this one?

Answer (score 3):

I've just created the item slider: check it out:
https://github.com/lingtalfi/jItemSlider/blob/master/README.md

It's 600 lines of code, maybe you can simply browse it.

The idea behind it is inspired by the netflix slider (as of 2016-02-24).

Basically, it uses css transform translations, because those are the fastest/slickest in a browser.

http://eng.wealthfront.com/2015/05/19/performant-css-animations/

Now the basic concept behind the slide movement, is that you only display the current visible slice, 
but you also have one invisible slice on the left, and another invisible slice on the right.

And, you also have two extra items, one on each side, so that your items look like this:

previous items   -   prev extra item  -   main items   -  next extra item   -   next items

Only the main items are visible.
The extra items are partially visible.
The previous and next items are invisible.

More details here:
https://github.com/lingtalfi/jItemSlider/blob/master/doc/conception.md

Now when you slide to the right (for instance), you basically append more items to the right side, 
and then remove those from the left side.

This technique is the greatest I've encountered so far, because you don't deal with a long list of items (using 
cloning without removing the invisible items), which can make your animation slower.

Note: my first try of this slider was actually cloning without removing, it works, but I don't like it:
https://github.com/lingtalfi/jInfiniteSlider

Also, it's item based (rather than pixels based), and in the end, that's what the user expects because 
everything is always aligned, as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

**Vanila Javascript!! No-clone technique, getElementsByClassName to the rescue**

document.getElementsByClassName selection is a live collection; any changes in DOM is updated in the stored variable unlike querySelector method.

In this technique, we just shift the first slide to the end if we reach the last slide while clicking right or we shift the last slide at the beginning when we reach the first slide while clicking left. Clone creation is not required here. The getElementsByClassName method gives us a live HTML collection to work with which updates as we make changes in the DOM. (In this case, changes in the order of divs)

Here is my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/dibakash/infinity-looping-rotating-slider)

```js
// slider
const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide"); // this selection is a live collection; any changes in DOM is updated in the variable unlike querySelectors
const btnLeft = document.querySelector(`.btn-left`);
const btnRight = document.querySelector(`.btn-right`);

let currentSlideIndex = 0;
let lastSlideIndex = slides.length - 1;

// go to a slide;
function goToSlide(slideIndex) {
    [...slides].forEach((s, i) => {
        s.style.transform = `translateX(${100 * (i - slideIndex)}%)`
    })
    currentSlideIndex = slideIndex;
}
goToSlide(currentSlideIndex);

// make ready the next slide if current slide is the first or the last slide
function readyNextSlide() {
    // if currentSlide is the last slide, shift the first slide to the end
    if (currentSlideIndex === lastSlideIndex) {
        slides[lastSlideIndex].insertAdjacentElement("afterend", slides[0]);
        slides[lastSlideIndex].style.transform = `translateX(${100}%)`;
        currentSlideIndex--; //this is because current slide is now the second last slide
    }
    // if currentSlide is the first slide, shift the last slide to the beginning
    if (currentSlideIndex === 0) {
        slides[0].insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", slides[lastSlideIndex]);
        slides[0].style.transform = `translateX(-${100}%)`;
        currentSlideIndex++; //this is because current slide is now the second slide
    }
}

// put the last slide in the beginning; ('if' condition is not necessary but providing if condition is future proof if user sets the initial slide to be shown as the last slide )
if (currentSlideIndex === lastSlideIndex || currentSlideIndex === 0) readyNextSlide();

// shift all slides left or right based on direction provided
function shiftSlides(direction) {
    direction ? currentSlideIndex++ : currentSlideIndex--
    if (currentSlideIndex === lastSlideIndex || currentSlideIndex === 0) readyNextSlide();
    goToSlide(currentSlideIndex);
}

//button click events
btnRight.addEventListener("click", shiftSlides.bind(null, 1));
btnLeft.addEventListener("click", shiftSlides.bind(null, 0));
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  overflow: hidden; /* remove overflow to see what's going on*/
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.slide b {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10em;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.s1 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.s2 {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.s3 {
  background-color: coral;
}

.s4 {
  background-color: thistle;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  border: none;
  background: crimson;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: white;
  height: 5.5rem;
  width: 5.5rem;
  font-size: 3.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-left {
  left: 6%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.btn-right {
  right: 6%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Infinity Looping Rotating slider</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css">
        <script src="slider.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide s1"><b>1</b></div>
            <div class="slide s2"><b>2</b></div>
            <div class="slide s3"><b>3</b></div>
            <div class="slide s4"><b>4</b></div>

            <button class="btn btn-left">&larr;</button>
            <button class="btn btn-right">&rarr;</button>
        </div>
        <p>
            <b>
                This is my response to a questing in <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/70340585/6216765">StackOverflow</a> about infinity loop slider.<br>
                My github repo is <a href="https://github.com/dibakash/infinity-looping-rotating-slider">Infinity loop Slider by Dibakash</a>
            </b>
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot of this article!
I  had update and used above code.
I hope this will help everyone.
Poor developer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Directive slider</title>
    <style>
        /* 四联切换焦点图 */
        .slides-wrapper{ position: relative;  width: 100%;  margin: 10px 0; }
        .gallery { position: relative;  width: 1200px;  height: 180px;  overflow:hidden;  }
        .gallery ul {  font-size: 0;  white-space: nowrap;  position: absolute;  top: 0;  left: -1200px;  margin: 0; padding: 0;  }
        .gallery li {  display: inline-block;  vertical-align: top;  width: 1200px;  height: 180px;  white-space: normal;  }
        .gallery li img{  width: 298px;  height:180px;  padding: 1px;  }
        .gallery .arrow { background: url(/shop/templates/default/images/home_bg.png) no-repeat; background-size: 150px 223px; width: 35px; height: 70px; position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 50px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;}
        .gallery .prev { background-position: 1px -92px; left: 0;}
        .gallery .next { background-position: -30px -92px; right: 0px;}
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        .demo_wrapper{
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 1200px;
        }
        .demo_wrapper .title{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo_wrapper">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Directive slider (Published by fenmingyu)</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- demo content -->
    <div class="slides-wrapper">
        <div class="gallery" id="top_sale_gallery">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-1-1.jpg?234" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-1-2.jpg?752" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-1-3.jpg?320" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-1-4.jpg?365" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-2-1.jpg?852" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-2-2.jpg?746" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-2-3.jpg?525" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-2-4.jpg?550" alt=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class='arrow prev'></div>
            <div class='arrow next'></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery" id="top_goods_gallery">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-3-1.jpg?793" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-3-2.jpg?180" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-3-3.jpg?550" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-3-4.jpg?851" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-1-1.jpg?234" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-1-2.jpg?752" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-1-3.jpg?320" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-1-4.jpg?365" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-2-1.jpg?852" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-2-2.jpg?746" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-2-3.jpg?525" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" title="" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="http://imgserv.5thmedia.cn/upload_test/shop/editor/web-102-104-2-4.jpg?550" alt=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class='arrow prev'></div>
            <div class='arrow next'></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.fn.gallery = function(settings) {
            var defaults = {
                time: 3000,
                direction:1
            };
            var settings = $.extend(defaults, settings);
            var gallery_wrapper = $(this),
                gallery = gallery_wrapper.find('ul'),
                items   = gallery.find('li'),
                len     = items.length,
                current = 1,  /* the current item we're looking */
                first   = items.filter(':first'),
                last    = items.filter(':last'),
                w = gallery.find('li').width(),
                triggers = gallery_wrapper.find('.arrow');
            var show_slide = function(direction,w){
                gallery.animate({ left: "+=" + (-w * direction) }, function() {

                    current += direction;

                    /**
                     * we're cycling the slider when the the value of "current"
                     * variable (after increment/decrement) is 0 or when it exceeds
                     * the initial gallery length
                     */
                    cycle = !!(current === 0 || current > len);

                    if (cycle) {
                        /* we switched from image 1 to 4-cloned or
                         from image 4 to 1-cloned */
                        current = (current === 0)? len : 1;
                        gallery.css({left:  -w * current });
                    }
                });
            };
            var picTimer = setInterval(function() {
                        show_slide(settings.direction,w);
                    },
                    settings.time);
            return this.each(function(){

                /* 1. Cloning first and last item */
                first.before(last.clone(true));
                last.after(first.clone(true));
                /* 2. Set button handlers */
                triggers.on('click', function() {
                    if (gallery.is(':not(:animated)')) {

                        var cycle = false;
                        settings.direction = ($(this).hasClass('prev'))? -1 : 1;
                        /* in the example buttons have id "prev" or "next" */
                        show_slide(settings.direction,w);
                    }
                    clearInterval(picTimer);
                    picTimer = setInterval(function() {
                                show_slide(settings.direction,w);
                            },
                            settings.time);
                });
                /* hover show arrows*/
                show_slide(settings.direction,w);

                gallery_wrapper.hover(function() {
                    $(this).find(".arrow").css("opacity", 0.0).stop(true, false).animate({
                                "opacity": "0.3"
                            },
                            300);
                },function(){
                    $(this).find(".arrow").css("opacity", 0.3).stop(true, false).animate({
                                "opacity": "0"
                            },
                            300);
                });
            });
        };
        $('#top_goods_gallery.gallery').gallery();
        $('#top_sale_gallery.gallery').gallery({
            time: 5000,
            direction:-1
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

te and use this in my project.