# Making a responsive image slider/carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, image-gallery

I'm creating my own slider and I need some help making it responsive.
Right now it works with the responsive part on the first slide, but when I go to the next slide (in this case, any li that is NOT first child) the positioning and width's of the li's doesn't add up and everything gets wrong.

It's hard to explain and I'd love if anyone could take a look here:

http://robbinj.se/r/

I have a wrapper with a width of 100% and every li's width gets set to the width of the wrapper of 100%. If you don't understand what I'm after try go to the page, resize your browser on the first slide, that is how I want it to work on all the other slides as well but I need some ideas on how to do it!

Here's the jQuery:

```
    var slideLiWidth = $('#slider').width(),
    slideUl = $('#slider ul'),
    slideLi = $(slideUl).find('li'),
    slides = $(slideLi).length,
    slideNav = $('.slideNav'),
    current = 1;

slideLi.width(slideLiWidth);

$(window).resize(function() {
    var slideLiWidth = $('#slider').width();
    slideLi.width(slideLiWidth);
});

slideNav.click(function() {
    dir = $(this).data('dir');
    transition();
});

function transition() {
    var slideLiWidth = $('#slider').width();
    if (dir === 'next' && current < slides) {
        slideUl.transition({x: '-='+slideLiWidth}, 500, 'ease');
        current++;
    }
    else if (dir === 'back' && current > 1) {
        slideUl.transition({x: '+='+slideLiWidth}, 500, 'ease');
        current--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the way you calculate the translate distance. You were correct in adding and subtracting the translate value of the current list item width, but didn't take into consideration the fact that said value does not update as users might resize their viewport.
Granted, this is only a problem for users who will, in fact, resize their viewport mid-browsing. Anyone using a tablet, for example, will have no problem with it.

Still, if you're really looking for a perfect slider, here's what I would do:
create a variable to keep count of which slide is currently active
use that variable to adjust the translate value in conformance with the resized viewport

Here's what that code looks like:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var slideCounter = 1; // Because the first slide is, well ... first.    
    var slideLiWidth = $('#slider').width();
    slideLi.width(slideLiWidth);
    slideUl.transition({x: '-='+slideCounter*slideLiWidth}, 500, 'ease'); // Adjust the UL's transition value to match the current slide position and width.
});

function transition() {
    var slideLiWidth = $('#slider').width();
    if (dir === 'next' && current < slides) {
        slideUl.transition({x: '-='+slideLiWidth}, 500, 'ease');
        current++;
        slideCounter++; // Increment the counter to keep up.
    }
    else if (dir === 'back' && current > 1) {
        slideUl.transition({x: '+='+slideLiWidth}, 500, 'ease');
        current--;
        slideCounter--; // Increment the counter to keep up.
    }
}
```

I've commented the added lines and, while I can't actually test the code above, I'm pretty sure it'll work. If it doesn't, at least I'm pointing you in the right direction.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for the help, but the slider goes crazy when i resize the browser now. You can see it for yourself: http://robbinj.se/r/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the choice to specify width and slide offset in pixels when you should instead try to define the width in `%` (so e.g. every `<li>` is `100%` wide) and when you animate your slider you will apply `transform: translate(-100%, 0)`, for the 2<sup>nd</sup> image, then `transform: translate(-200%, 0)` for the 3<sup>rd</sup> and so on.

This should work fine even when you resize the browser, since your negative offset and the applied width will be ever automatically recalculated along with the browser size. The browser will turn your relative offset into the correct amount of pixel.

Take a look at this fiddle for a proof of concept (tried on firefox and chrome) : http://jsbin.com/ecifoc/1/ (move the slider and resize the browser, then move slider again)

Other methods like continuous recalculation of the width and negative offset may work fine too, but they are definitely too much expensive (typically, you need to attach some handler to the `resize` event) and make the code more error-prone because you introduce some complexity.

---

**Note:** if you need to also manage an infinity slider you can look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15877302/1098851)

Comment: Thanks for the help, the fiddle contains a really good slider working exactly the way I need it to!

Comment: @Fabrizio - After playing with this a bit, I noticed the font-size:0;. I thought I was clever and used this for combining both images and text.  When I removed the font-size, obviously I could see my text but also throws the slides off by a few pixels when cycling through them.  What exact role is the font-size:0; on the ul playing in this?  You suppose there's a work around for removing it so I can add text to this too?  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think this one will help. This one will be working in small devices and tablets also. You can have multiple carousels on the same page as well. Just replicate the "DIV"-"SpecDataWrap" and change the ID.

```
<div class="ContainerWrap">
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="AllSpecsDataWrap">
            <div class="SpecDataWrap" id="SpecDataWrap1">
                <div class="SpecDataSlides activeNavSlide">
                    <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/lzem156s3/image1.jpg" />
                    <div class="SpecDesc SpecDescRight">
                        <h2>Choose to be unique.</h2>
                        <div class="SpecDescDetails">
                            Metal accents, colorful hues, real woods and leathers, and a customizable laser-etched signature offer thousands of ways to make your Moto X unique.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="SpecDataSlides InActiveNavSlide">
                    <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/6cira13mb/image2.jpg" />
                    <div class="SpecDesc SpecDescLeft">
                        <h2>Choose to be unique.</h2>
                        <div class="SpecDescDetails">
                            Metal accents, colorful hues, real woods and leathers, and a customizable laser-etched signature offer thousands of ways to make your Moto X unique.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="SpecDataSlides InActiveNavSlide">
                    <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/f4zpxpor7/image3.jpg" />
                    <div class="SpecDesc SpecDescRight">
                        <h2>Choose to be unique.</h2>
                        <div class="SpecDescDetails">
                            Metal accents, colorful hues, real woods and leathers, and a customizable laser-etched signature offer thousands of ways to make your Moto X unique.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="SpecSlideNavigation">
                    <div class="leftNavSpec SpecSlideNav"></div>
                    <div class="bulletsNavSpec">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="activeImage"></li>
                            <li class="InActiveImage"></li>
                            <li class="InActiveImage"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clearFix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="RightNavSpec SpecSlideNav"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearFix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the JS and CSS code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/raju_sumit/Ld21vutz/

Comment: Can you please explain me how it works in safari browser

Answer (score 0):

```
var $slider = $('#slider'),
    imgW = $('#slider li').outerWidth(true),
    winW = 0,
    zero = 0;



function getSizes(){
    winW = $(window).width();
    zero = (winW-imgW)/2;
    $slider.animate({left: zero},0); // This should 'zero' the position on resize
}

getSizes(); 


$(window).resize(function() {
    getSizes();
});
```

If I missed something, retrieve the logic here: http://roxon.in/scripts/infinite_gal/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the help, I didnt get it to work exactly how I want it for now but i'll look further into it!

Comment: @robbinj you're welcome. If you give more info may be I'll be able to help?!

Comment: Has anyone ever tried to use the above jsbin with <p> content? I'm trying to incorporate this with half image and half text and the text just disappears?

Comment: @DennySmith I have no jsBin.com demo. Are you sure you commented the right answer?

Comment: Actually, you're correct. I did comment on the wrong answer but this is the jsbin.  http://jsbin.com/ecifoc/1  I also figured out the answer.  The problem was staring me right in the face. There was a    font-size: 0; in the css.  Sometimes it's the dumbest things.  Thanks!

Comment: @DennySmith yep it happens :) glad you figured out your issue