# Make an infinite slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I made a home made slider where I add a class on the slide section in view and an other class for the preview one but i can't find a solution for make it come back to the first slide section how can I make it infinite?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var ul = $('.project ul'),
    li = ul.find('li');

var $next=$('#arrow');

li.eq(0).addClass('prev');
li.eq(1).addClass('active');


$next.on('click', function(){
    $(li.get().reverse()).filter('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
  $(li.get().reverse()).filter('.prev').removeClass('prev').next().addClass('prev');
});

});
```

```css
.project-bg{
 position:absolute;
 height:75vh;
 width:25vw;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-top:-37.5vh;
 margin-left:-35vw;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.project-bg .bg-in{
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.project-bg:nth-child(2) .bg-in{
 background:red;
}

.project-bg:nth-child(3) .bg-in{
background:blue;
}
.project-bg:nth-child(4) .bg-in{
background:yellow;
}
.project-bg:nth-child(5) .bg-in{
background:orange;
}

.project-bg .bg-in{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0)
}

.project-bg.active .bg-in{
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0)
}

.project-bg.prev .bg-in{
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)
}

#arrow{
 position:absolute;
 height:20px;
 width:60px;
 right:0%;
 bottom:0%;
 margin-right:250px;
 margin-bottom:50px;
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project">
 
        <ul>
         <li class="project-bg"><div class="bg-in"></div></li>
         <li class="project-bg"><div class="bg-in"></div></li>
            <li class="project-bg"><div class="bg-in"></div></li>
            <li class="project-bg"><div class="bg-in"></div></li>
            <li class="project-bg"><div class="bg-in"></div></li>
         </ul>
           
        </div>
        
         <div id="arrow">
        <svg id="arrow-svg" viewBox="0 0 60 20">
 <polygon points="56.1,9.3 49.7,11.6 49.7,7.1 "/>
 <g>
  <rect x="3.9" y="8.8" width="46" height="1"/>
 </g>
 </svg>
      </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinity Loop Slider Concepts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876754/infinity-loop-slider-concepts)

Comment: actually i didn't use a slider plugin because i didn't want to use the left css property  [ gallery.animate({ left: "+=" + (-100 * delta) } ]

Answer (score 0):

Check for last li. If yes add active class to first li. That's it.
Check below link -
`jsfiddle:`
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxkhH/)

Comment: Could you post the code here as well? And also, the link isn't active.