# Image Slider w/ Controls

Tags: javascript, slider, smoothing

Building a simple javascript slider with controls, I'm having a hard time with the control triggers (*left,right -arrows*) and dealing with the loop moving smoothly from left-to-right when transitioning to end-to-beginning or vice-versa.

```
function Slider(tag,count){
    var self = this;
    this.build=(buildset)=>build(buildset,self),
    this.activeSlide = 0;
    this.totalSlides = count,
    this.slideWidth = (window.screen.width * -self.totalSlides), 
    this.getSlider=()=>get(tag),
    this.controls={
        left:()=>{
        },
        right:()=>{
            var slider = self.getSlider();
            append(slider,slider.children[0]);
            self.clear();
            setTimeout(()=>self.start(), 5000);
            self.activeSlide++;
            self.activeSlide = (self.activeSlide === self.totalSlides) ? 0 : self.activeSlide;
            var slideTo = window.screen.width * -self.activeSlide;
            slider.style.transform = "translateX("+slideTo+"px)";
        }   
    },
    this.start=()=>{
        this.interval = setInterval(()=>{
            var slider = self.getSlider();
            append(slider,slider.children[0]);
            self.activeSlide++;
            self.activeSlide = (self.activeSlide === self.totalSlides) ? 0 : self.activeSlide;
            var slideTo = window.screen.width * -self.activeSlide;
            slider.style.transform = "translateX("+slideTo+"px)";
        },5000);
    },
    this.clear=()=>{
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}
```

//HTML

```
<wrapper data-wrapper="slider">
     <control class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left fa-2x"></control>
     <slider id="slide1">
         <img src="/media/slide-1.jpg">
         <img src="/media/slide-2.jpg">
         <img src="/media/slide-3.jpg">
     </slider>
     <control class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-2x"></control>
</wrapper>
```

**Question:** How can I make the slider transistion from end-to-start, start-to-end an "infinite" loop with the smooth left-to-right (ease)?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] add HTML and CSS as well.

Comment: @zer00ne I'm using a dynamic assembler function I wrote called "build" so I feed a JSON object which is the instruction set on how to "assemble". I'll post the end result though.

Comment: `slider.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in"`

Comment: @zer00ne yeah thats not the problem is when it slides 3-to-1 or 1-to-3

Comment: Clone the first and last slides and position the clones accordingly.

Comment: @zer00ne yeah thats exactly what I was thinking

Comment: Great minds think alike, sir. Here's a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15877302/2813224) from a greater mind.

Comment: @zer00ne yeah thats good post. I think it is the only way I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve it, if the slider contains high-res images could be a problem.

Comment: I've been there before, it's a b@tch. Lazy loading and reformatting hires images to interleaved helped, but it all boiled down to if the user's bandwidth can handle such a beast.