# how to Infinite Horizontal Scroll with cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Hey I need some help figuring out how to achieve an infinite horizontal scroll that moves on cursor position...

Basically i have a slider like this :

A - B - C - D

When the users moves the cursor to the right the slider should slide towards D and when it arrives to D , A has to show up again like this (C - D - A - B)

When the users moves the cursor to the left , the slider should slide toward A and D should show up again (D - A - B)...

I managed to make it scroll using Jquery mousemove and some css but the infinite functionality is tricky

Hope someone can help...

Thank you in advance

Comment: paste your current code that you have in question

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876754/infinity-loop-slider-concepts/15877302 ?