# The returned Boolean value converted to the Boolean value

Tags: javascript, boolean

Here is some code : [Infinity Loop Slider Concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876754/infinity-loop-slider-concepts), there is boolean statement, that return true or false, and than again convert it to boolean with double operator (!), the line of code:

```
cycle = !!(current === 0 || current > len);
```

So a'm interesting why autor used !!(//code), as i know !! сonverts the value to a logical  true / false ,but the code have already return boolean value (current === 0 || current > len) // true / false.
Please explain or (!!) was unnecessary?

Comment: No need for `!!` here. You might want to comment that post and ask.

Comment: Thanks, this was an old enough question, so I thought that the author would not answer and i created a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`===` returns a boolean, which means `current === 0` returns a boolean, `>` returns a boolean, which means `current > len` returns a boolean, which means `current === 0 || current > len` returns a boolean. Casting that to a boolean yet again is absolutely superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any sense in this example since the condition can just be truthy or falsy

with the double negation you force "cycle" to be a "[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/truthy) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)" value

lets say you run this code

```
if (variable.guess) {
    // would be executed if variable.guess containts a not falsy value
}
```

that does not mean

```
variable.guess === true
```

Comment: Thanks,if i will use !!(variable.guess), (variable.guess === true) will be true. (!!) is not required if we have boolean type?

Comment: Your first sentence seems to contradict the rest of this answer, or it's just very unclear what you're trying to say.

Comment: That is correct. It would be needed if it was like `!!(current || somethingElse)` because technically || as an operator returns either of the arguments that is truthy which means not strictly boolean.

Comment: @Alex thats right with (!!) you can be 100% sure its a boolean type

Answer (score -1):

The `||` operator behaves like so:

```
a || b // returns a if a is truthy
a || b // returns b if a is falsy
```

That is why you see it used to set a default value

```
var foo = bar || 'something'; // if bar is falsy (like undefined) the operator returns 'something'
```

As mentioned in the previous answers both `current === 0` and `current > len` are Boolean types so `!!`, which is commonly used to convert a value to pure Boolean type, is of no value here since `Boolean || Boolean` already returns a Boolean.

But while the code in question is wrong or unnecessary (wrong in my opinion) it doesn't mean that it's not a tricky part in Javascript.

Usually all you want in Javascript is value that get coerced to a Boolean type but let's say you absolutely need a Boolean and you had the below code:

```
var result = current || current > 5
```

if `current === 'foo'` then `result === 'foo'`

what if you were doing something with `result` later in the code
like:

`finalResult = result + 1`

If `result === 'foo'` then `finalResult === 'foo1'` but if `result === false` then `finalResult === 1`.

These times you just wish you were using a static typed language.

Practically though, all you need in Javascript is type coercion and only care for these pecculiar things when concating strings with variables.