# Infinite Horizontal Scrool Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, infinite

I have this html code that creates a horizontal scroll, what I need is an infinite loop to be created by scrolling to the right and then going back to the beginning. "An infinite Slider"

I also need the code to work on mobiles.

This would be the code already uploaded in codepen.

I currently have this code but it doesn't work on mobiles. I do not understand why

```
window.onload = function () {
   !(function t(e, n) {
       var o = $(e).get(0).scrollWidth,
           c = $(e).get(0).clientWidth;
       $(e).animate(
           { scrollLeft: o - c },
           {
               duration: n,
               complete: function () {
                   e.animate(
                       { scrollLeft: 0 },
                       {
                           duration: n,
                           complete: function () {
                               t(e, n);
                           },
                       }
                   );
               },
           }
       );
   })($("#slidertrubiproducto"), 5000);
};
```

```
https://codepen.io/eduardogt/pen/xxdYBRE
```

Comment: You're better off using js sliders like swiper.js which are made more or less for this purpose

Comment: Reviewed it thank you very much

Comment: To understand the concepts and what you (or a third-party tool) have to do, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876754/infinity-loop-slider-concepts