# JavaScript loop slider by bind method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a loop slider and I saw a great solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70340585/18736427

I understand how the function `shiftSlides()` works here:

```
function shiftSlides(direction) {
    direction ? currentSlideIndex++ : currentSlideIndex--
    if (currentSlideIndex === lastSlideIndex || currentSlideIndex === 0) readyNextSlide();
    goToSlide(currentSlideIndex);
}
```

what I don't understand is how he uses the bind method to control the direction? What is the number 1 and 0 means here?

```
btnRight.addEventListener("click", shiftSlides.bind(null, 1));
btnLeft.addEventListener("click", shiftSlides.bind(null, 0));
```

Comment: It is due to a design choice as one can see at [line 39 within the `shiftSlides`](https://github.com/dibakash/infinity-looping-rotating-slider/blob/main/slider.js#L39) implementation ... `1` is truthy and `0` is falsy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`direction` just becomes `1` and `0` respectively. They could just as easily be `true` or `false`. The `bind` method just takes a series of arguments and passes them into the function they're bound to producing a new function.

eg:

```js
btnRight.addEventListener("click", shiftSlides.bind(null, true));
btnLeft.addEventListener("click", shiftSlides.bind(null, false));
```

Comment: Good point, but why 1 is true and 0 is false?...

Comment: That's just a javascript notion of "truthy". JS treats all sorts of stuff as true in a condition. any number not 0 as `true` as well as any non-empty string. Any object or array is treated as true. If you're asking why js was programmed that way, I couldn't answer that question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy