# Making a loop slider

Tags: javascript

I'm following this great solution to make a slider https://stackoverflow.com/a/70340585/18736427

It uses a good technique where once the slide reaches the first/last slide, it will insert the first/last slide respectively into the first/last place to make a loop effect.

However, this effect is instant...When you click next once it reaches the last slide, the first slide will always immediately be inserted which causes a weird animation sight.

You can run the code snippet to have an idea, the animation looks good before 5, but it will be weird after it.

I've tried the `setTimeout` method but it looks even weird because it just flies over to the right side every time when you click the next button.

```js
// slider
const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide"); // this selection is a live collection; any changes in DOM is updated in the variable unlike querySelectors
const btnLeft = document.querySelector(`.btn-left`);
const btnRight = document.querySelector(`.btn-right`);

let currentSlideIndex = 0;
let lastSlideIndex = slides.length - 1;

// go to a slide;
function goToSlide(slideIndex) {
    [...slides].forEach((s, i) => {
        s.style.transform = `translateX(${110 * (i - slideIndex)}%)`
    })
    currentSlideIndex = slideIndex;
}
goToSlide(currentSlideIndex);

// make ready the next slide if current slide is the first or the last slide
function readyNextSlide() {
    // if currentSlide is the last slide, shift the first slide to the end
    if (currentSlideIndex === lastSlideIndex) {
        slides[lastSlideIndex].insertAdjacentElement("afterend", slides[0]);
        slides[lastSlideIndex].style.transform = `translateX(${110}%)`;
        currentSlideIndex--; //this is because current slide is now the second last slide
    }
    // if currentSlide is the first slide, shift the last slide to the beginning
    if (currentSlideIndex === 0) {
        slides[0].insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", slides[lastSlideIndex]);
        slides[0].style.transform = `translateX(-${110}%)`;
        currentSlideIndex++; //this is because current slide is now the second slide
    }
}

// put the last slide in the beginning; ('if' condition is not necessary but providing if condition is future proof if user sets the initial slide to be shown as the last slide )
if (currentSlideIndex === lastSlideIndex || currentSlideIndex === 0) readyNextSlide();

// shift all slides left or right based on direction provided
function shiftSlides(direction) {
    direction ? currentSlideIndex++ : currentSlideIndex--
    if (currentSlideIndex === lastSlideIndex || currentSlideIndex === 0) readyNextSlide();
    goToSlide(currentSlideIndex);
}

//button click events
btnRight.addEventListener("click", shiftSlides.bind(null, 1));
btnLeft.addEventListener("click", shiftSlides.bind(null, 0));
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  overflow: hidden; /* remove overflow to see what's going on*/
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.slide b {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10em;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.s1 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.s2 {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.s3 {
  background-color: coral;
}

.s4 {
  background-color: thistle;
}

.s5 {
  background-color: blueViolet;
}

.s6 {
  background-color: darkGreen;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  border: none;
  background: crimson;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: white;
  height: 5.5rem;
  width: 5.5rem;
  font-size: 3.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-left {
  left: 6%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.btn-right {
  right: 6%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide s1"><b>1</b></div>
    <div class="slide s2"><b>2</b></div>
    <div class="slide s3"><b>3</b></div>
    <div class="slide s4"><b>4</b></div>
    <div class="slide s5"><b>5</b></div>
    <div class="slide s6"><b>6</b></div>

    <button class="btn btn-left">&larr;</button>
    <button class="btn btn-right">&rarr;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Code snippet works fine for me.

Comment: @geertjanknapen Yes, the code snippet is working fine but it looks weird once it reaches the last slide ( the fifth one ), please have a try

Comment: Code snippet goes up until 6 and slides from 6 to 1 fine..

Comment: @geertjanknapen the slider is working and got no problem...Please look at my question...It's about the animation sight

Comment: Yeah I get your question, I'm just noting I'm not experiencing any weird thing with the animation, even when reaching the last slide.

Comment: @geertjanknapen Have you noticed the right side...before slide 5 and after slide 5...

Comment: Quickest way to see the "weird" appearance is to click the left arrow and note that the "6" block appears to be initially merged with the "5" block.  After doing so, click right, then left again to see the preferred animation.

Comment: @phatfingers Yes, that's exactly what I mean! Thank you so much for clarifying for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move to the next slide you check if you're at the last one and move the first slide back to the right. But because you always show part of the next image you're actually too late at that point: you need to check for the 'one **before** last' slide. This will give you time to move the next slide into place. Same in the other direction.

You're also doing the same check multiple times (you check if you need to call `readyNextSlide`, but inside that function you're doing the same check again. So I moved `readyNextSlide` into the `goToSlide` function for simplicity.

The below code isn't perfect (for example, it doesn't show slide 6 at the start because it is moved to the back (you should be able to fix that by starting at slide #2) and clicking very quickly will make the slides disappear for a bit (fixable by adding some sort of blocking to clicking until the movement is done, or by using the slide positions instead of just the index in code) but it should help.

See the changes to `readyNextSlide` which now moves the slides 220% instead of 110%, and is called when you're at the one before last or one before first slide:

```
// slider
const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide"); // this selection is a live collection; any changes in DOM is updated in the variable unlike querySelectors
const btnLeft = document.querySelector(`.btn-left`);
const btnRight = document.querySelector(`.btn-right`);

let currentSlideIndex = 0;
let lastSlideIndex = slides.length - 1;

// go to a slide;
function goToSlide(slideIndex) {
    [...slides].forEach((s, i) => {
        s.style.transform = `translateX(${110 * (i - slideIndex)}%)`
    })
    currentSlideIndex = slideIndex;
    readyNextSlide();
}
goToSlide(currentSlideIndex);

// make ready the next slide if current slide is the first or the last slide
function readyNextSlide() {
    // if currentSlide is the last slide, shift the first slide to the end
    if (currentSlideIndex === lastSlideIndex - 1) {
      slides[lastSlideIndex].insertAdjacentElement("afterend", slides[0]);
      slides[lastSlideIndex].style.transform = `translateX(${220}%)`;
      currentSlideIndex--; //this is because current slide is now the second last slide
    }
    // if currentSlide is the first slide, shift the last slide to the beginning
    if (currentSlideIndex === 1) {
        slides[0].insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", slides[lastSlideIndex]);
        slides[0].style.transform = `translateX(-${220}%)`;
        currentSlideIndex++; //this is because current slide is now the second slide
    }
}

// put the last slide in the beginning; ('if' condition is not necessary but providing if condition is future proof if user sets the initial slide to be shown as the last slide )

// shift all slides left or right based on direction provided
function shiftSlides(direction) {
    direction ? currentSlideIndex++ : currentSlideIndex--
    if (currentSlideIndex === lastSlideIndex || currentSlideIndex === 0) readyNextSlide();
    goToSlide(currentSlideIndex);
}

//button click events
btnRight.addEventListener("click", shiftSlides.bind(null, 1));
btnLeft.addEventListener("click", shiftSlides.bind(null, 0));
```